# stitching together 3d scans

Tags: rendering, snapping

I used [polycam](https://poly.cam/) to make 3D scans of [Kiwanis Cabin](https://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/cibola/recarea/?recid=64314). I scanned the cabin in 5 different parts because there's an upper bound to how big polycam scans can be. It doesn't tell you when you're approaching the memory limit, either, so you kinda have to guess. It's not a huge issue, however, because, in theory, you should be able to [stitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching) the scans together. One problem with this approach, however, is that often times there'll be bad parts of each scan.

For example, here's one scan (Oct6,3-32PM-poly.glb) that has some issues in certain spots:

[image]

Here's another scan (Oct6,3-27PM-poly.glb) that does not have those issues in those spots:

[image]

So you'd need to cut the bad spots out. Now, from these pics, one might think that using the second scan would be the best bet but the first scan captures things the second scan doesn't. Namely, exterior shots. Hence the desire to stitch them together.

This could be done by hand but having an automated tool do it for you is just waaaay easier. My question is...  does such a tool exist?

Here are the scans if anyone wants to give it a go:

https://terrafrost.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/kiwanis/Oct6,3-31PM-poly.glb
https://terrafrost.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/kiwanis/Oct6,3-27PM-poly.glb
https://terrafrost.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/kiwanis/Oct6,3-23PM-poly.glb
https://terrafrost.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/kiwanis/Oct6,3-37PM-poly.glb
https://terrafrost.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/kiwanis/Oct6,3-40PM-poly.glb